# can maven assembly plugin picking the specify java package?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Suppose we have following packages in our project

> org.xxx.dao, org.xxx.service, org.xxx.service.impl

all the package are in ther source folder src/main/java

> can i assembly packages into seprated jars,(xxx-dao.jar,xxx-service.jar,xxx-service-impl.jar)?

Comment: why don't you create multiple modules instead of writing them in a single module? Or if you don't want to do this, why do you want separate jars?

Comment: That's because the old project are not created by me. I only want to export part of the source then throw the jar in another system to run.

Comment: I've added an answer, can you validate that it works? If it doesn't work, please let me know so that I can delete the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the standard `maven-jar-plugin` for this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>dao</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <classifier>dao</classifier>
                <includes>
                    <include>org/xxx/dao/**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>service</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <classifier>service</classifier>
                <includes>
                    <include>org/xxx/service/**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This gives you one JAR with everything and then several JARs with only the selected content which you can select with a classifier in your Maven POMs.

If you want to omit the default JAR (which contains everything), then you replace one `<id>` with `<id>default-jar</id>` and add an `<excludes>` element because the default JAR includes everything, so you have to get rid of anything that you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

maven-assembly plugin is not intended for this kind of tasks, see [its features](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/features.html). If you have the source codes, then I would suggest copying them into a module of your project.

But if you want to do it with maven-assembly plugin, then I think you can do it by creating separate [descriptor components](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html) and defining which files to include in which assembly. You can define source files to be included in `includes` tags under [sources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html#class_sources) definition.