# How to create Maven artifact with containing a subset of module files?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I need to produce an artifact from Maven module, which will contain only `*Foo.class` files from `./target/classes`. It has to be a proper artifact that can be used later as a normal dependency for another project. It means that it has to contain its own `pom.xml`. I tried `maven-dependency-plugin` and `maven-shade-plugin` to no avail:

- `maven-dependency-plugin` doesn't generate `pom.xml`, but only copies files into JAR - this is not enough for a Maven dependency
- `maven-shade-plugin` doesn't allow to pick files by mask, and besides that it unpacks all dependencies into target artifact (which is not what I need).

What is a possible workaround?

Comment: Are you sure maven-shade-plugin does not allow masking? see shade includes and excludes: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Comment: `include/exclude` in shade plugin is used to filter content of module dependencies, not content of the module itself.

Comment: Is the `pom.xml` of this artifact the same as that of the `module`?

Comment: No, it has to be different. Key difference is in dependencies list. I need this new `pom.xml` to have all dependencies from the module in `compile` scope, no matter what scope they had before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `maven-jar-plugin` with several executions, `includes`/`excludes` plus `classifier` to put your classes into several artifacts.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209544/34088

Comment: @yegor256.  How did you ensure the artifact had a custom `pom.xml`?